# How do I properly handle mouseover if the function obscures the element?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I have a grid composed of many:

```
<div id="block4-2" class="base" onmouseover="showSubElements(this);" 
     onmouseout="hideSubElements(this)"></div>
```

showSubElements() creates button elements and adds them to the div's innerHTML:

```
function showSubElements(divelem) {
    var row = divelem.id[6];
    var col = divelem.id[8];

    var a = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    a.setAttribute("class", "itemA subelem");
    a.setAttribute("id", "button" + col + "-" + row + "a");
    a.setAttribute("onclick", "console.log('TEST');");

    [repeat code for b, c and d]

    var a_str = "<button id=\"" + a.id + "\" " + "onclick=\"" + "console.log(\'TEST\');\" class=\"" + a.getAttribute("class") + "\"></button>";

    [repeat code for b, c and d]

    divelem.innerHTML = a_str + b_str + c_str + d_str;
}
```

hideSubElements():

```
function hideSubElements(divelem) {
    divelem.innerHTML = "";
}
```

The problem with this code is that when the mouse is over the div element it's over the button sub elements too since they are styled to each occupy a quadrant of the box they're in so they flicker as I move the mouse in the box and dissapear when the mouse stops moving.

Comment: I dn understand why you are using `mouseover`, but as long as your are moving the mouse, the html of the element is getting updated repeatedly  and so the browser as to re-render them. So you see a flicker, if you can do a delay, then the flicker might reduce, but however, if you can move the logic out of mouseover, or replace only the buttons text, or onlick or styles as required, the flicker wont happen.

Comment: What do you propose I use instead of mouseover?

Comment: Depends on ur logic,, why do u want to update, how frequently do you want too update.. all those things..

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because every mouse movement within the div will cause *showSubElements(this)* to be executed again.

You should disable showSubElements(this) until the mouse has left the div (onmouseout)

Comment: I don't think that's the case because if I disabled one of the buttons and hover the mouse over the empty square it works as intended which is why I assumed in the title that the button elements are obscuring the div, so mouseenter -> showbutton -> mouseexit(blocked by button) -> hidebutton -> repeat